# FastAPI use two buttons for the same form

Tags: html, fastapi

I have the following question.
I have a form in html which contains 4 fields and two buttons

1. ID Worker
2. Start_date
3. End_date
4. Salary_per_date.

The first button sends the data to calculate the salary of **ID_WORKER** from **Start_date** to **End-date**.

```
        <form class="ui form" action="/attendance" method="post">
            <div class="field">
                <table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>ID de Trabajador</label></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="id_worker" placeholder="Ingresar trabajador" style="width:200px"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Fecha inicial</label></td>
                        <td><input type="date"  name="start_date" placeholder="Fecha inicial" style="width:200px"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Fecha final</label></td>
                        <td><input type="date"  name="end_date" placeholder="Fecha final" style="width:200px"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Sueldo por día</label></td>
                        <td><input type="number"  name="day_wage" placeholder="Sueldo por día" style="width:200px"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <button class="ui blue button" type="submit">Calcular asistencias</button>

        </form>
```

This is processed by:

```
@app.post("/attendance")
async def attendance_image(request: Request, id_worker: int = Form(...), start_date: date = Form(...),
                           end_date: date = Form(...), day_wage: int = Form(...)):
    user = [id_worker]
    start_date = datetime(start_date.year, start_date.month, start_date.day)
    end_date = datetime(end_date.year, end_date.month, end_date.day)
    attendance = filter_by_date(zk, user, start_date, end_date)
    user_history = attendance_to_dict(attendance)
    dates, data, days, errors = data_to_july(user_history, start_date, end_date)

    axes = create_july_image(dates, data, days, errors, day_wage)
    fig = axes.get_figure()
    plt.axes(axes)
    img_buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(img_buf, format='PNG')
    plt.close(fig)
    png = img_buf.getvalue()
    img_buf.close()
    base64_encoded_image = base64.b64encode(png).decode("utf-8")
    title = [user_list[id_worker], start_date.strftime("%d/%m/%y") + " - " + end_date.strftime("%d/%m/%y")]
    return templates.TemplateResponse("base.html",
                                      {"request": request,
                                       "user_list": user_list,
                                       "title": title,
                                       "img": base64_encoded_image})
```

I want to add another button that will generate a pdf for all workers, it will only need **Start_date** from Form. I'm trying first to get **start_date** with

```
`@app.get("/pdf")
def generate_report(request: Request, start_date: Date = Form(...)):
    print(start_date)
    return {"message": "message"}`
```

```
        <a class="ui red button" href="/pdf">Generar reporte</a>
```

I was expecting on getting the start_date.
But instead I get the following

`{"detail":[{"loc":["body","start_date"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}`

I don't know how to make the second button work and return only the optional parameter of **start_date**

Comment: You're not including a `start_date` with the `/pdf` link - if start_date is optional (and not present in this case?), define it as such and give it a default value: `start_date: Optional[Date] = None` - also - there generally isn't any `Form` data for a _get_ request, so you'll have to decide what you're actually trying to do here - either use a POST request with Form, or use a regular URL parameter with a GET request.

Comment: If you're going to have two buttons in the same form, you'll have to give them a name and a value and check if either of those buttons are included (and check it in your endpoint manually) - the UX might be better with two separate forms that indicate which information is necessary for each operation, though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer as @MatsLindh suggested was to create separate forms or to add a function for each button.

```
        <button class="ui blue button" formaction="/attendance" type="submit">Calcular asistencias</button>
        <button class="ui red button" formaction="/pdf" type="submit">Generar Reporte</button>
```